# Changing the body using an exchange transport agent not reflecting in the sent items

Tags: routes, exchange-server, transport

I have written an exchange transport agent routing agent on the onRoutedMessage event.
And I'm changing the body in the transport agent to something else. The recipient is receiving the changes email body but it is not being reflected in the senders sent items.

Is it the valid behaviour or do I have to do something else to get it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

work with this object, you'll have access to the massage body via the routing agent:

```
messageEventArgs.MailItem.Message.Body
```

Answer (score 1):

Changes in the sent items folder won't be sync'd to Outlook in cached mode.  This is by design and is done for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I change the eMail body via EWS. It takes effect on the sender's email.